# Rubygems doesn't add /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin to $PATH?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

My question is, why does rubygems on Ubuntu not add /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin to $PATH ?

I see in the
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails#Installing%20RubyGems

page that it says you have to add it yourself, but I don't understand why there is an extra step.
Testing it on a Debian system, rubygems <strike>*does*</strike> does not make the modification to $PATH automatically.
I'm wondering if this is a bug, or if I'm misunderstanding something - I know Ubuntu and Debian have many differences, perhaps this is just one of them.
I posted the question to answers.launchpad.net but have not yet gotten any response.

Comment: I highly recommend using [RVM](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/). It automatically manages all this stuff for you and allows you to switch between multiple installs of Ruby on the same machine.

Comment: This seems much more like a rant than a question. Can you rephrase it so it is less rhetorical? As is, I suspect it will be closed.

Comment: I'm maintaining the TicGit-ng gem, and when people install it via rubygems on Ubuntu, they have to manually add the gems bin directory to their $PATH because rubygems doesn't do it for them.  I do use RVM when developing, but I can't ask every one of the gem's users to use it as well just to solve this problem.

Comment: @Tin Man, Hmm.  I'll try, I honestly thought it was fairly well worded though.  Thanks for the constructive criticism :)

Comment: I think it's a fair question. There are plenty of Ubuntu contributors who think this issue should be addressed as well -- see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gems/+bug/145267. Basically, the Ubuntu team has known about this problem for years, but a bunch of infighting has prevented any progress from being made.

Answer (score 2):

RubyGems *never* adds anything to the `$PATH`, whether on Ubuntu or otherwise. Nor does APT (or any other packaging system I know).

The `$PATH` variable is *clearly* in the user's domain. No program should ever mess with it.

Comment: @Jeff Welling: Because you just so happened to have the gem binary directory already in your `$PATH`.

Comment: Epic *facepalm* moment right there.  Thanks for answering what was ostensibly a stupid question lol :)